# CSS: Show checkmark in top right of a td

Tags: html, css

I am trying to show a checkmark in the top right corner of a td. I can't seem to get it there without expanding the whole tr. This is my table:

```
<tr style="position:relative;>
    <td><p class="mark" style="position:relative; left:10px;></p><input type="text"></td> <-- in this td the icon should be placed. 
     ...more rows...
</tr>
```

I just tried using a class for the icon and making the tr relative and the td relative but it keeps expanding the td's height.

Any ideas?

Comment: of every td, or only for first td ?

Comment: only first td gets a mark

Comment: please include your css so that its easier to identify the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `first-child` selector and `background-position` attribute to show icon on right top of first td

```
tr:first-child td:first-child
{
    background-image:url('http://files.softicons.com/download/toolbar-icons/iconza-light-green-icons-by-turbomilk/png/32/check_mark.png');
    background-position:right top;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding-right:35px;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
}
```

You can shorten this like

```
tr:first-child td:first-child
    {
        background:url('http://files.softicons.com/download/toolbar-icons/iconza-light-green-icons-by-turbomilk/png/32/check_mark.png') no-repeat right top red;
        padding:5px 35px 5px 0
    }
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sua5Y/1/)

Comment: @MouNtant I assumed you need foreground image so showed the position:asolute method.. Anyway good luck

Comment: @Sowmya the solution is invalid anyway, as stated in my post you cannot use `position:relative` on a `td`-element. Also I have no idea why this solution is accepted since it hardcodes the checkmark to the first cell of the first row - no flexibility whatsoever.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes look this comment *only first td gets a mark* above by OP. that's why I have used first-child.

Comment: @Sachin the question title and content state "a td", and I interpret that answer as "in this case only the first TD". I don't really see the point of hardcoding in CSS that the first element always has a checkmark - might as well just put a background on the entire `table` then, shorter and easier CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot use a `position` rule on table cells (prohibited by standards, only strictly enforced by Gecko) you have to use a workaround with another element inside, or use some other solution. Also you shouldn't be generating images for 'semantic' stuff like this, use classes, makes it both easier to generate, and easy to manipulate with JS.

#### HTML

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="checked">...data 1...<br>multiline</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>...data 2...</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="checked">...data 3...</td>
</tr>   
</table>
```

#### CSS

```
td{
    background:#fcf4cf;
}
td.checked:before {
    content:url(http://www.kyoceradocumentsolutions.com.au/Style%20Library/en-us/Images1/TickMark.gif);
    float:right;
    padding-left:4px;
}
```

<kbd>[See this work on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/4dpjm/3/)</kbd>

This is compatible with all major browsers and semantically more correct than your current approach, with shorter CSS and HTML.